# Android button for recording sensor data

Tags: java, android, sensors

I am beginner in Android platform. I wrote code, which I have pasted below, for recording the data from my magnetic sensor on click of button. But when I click button (button id - **btnRecord**), it just record data for some seconds and I have to click again to record more. How can I start recording data continuously with first click? Thank you in advance.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    a= event.values[0];
    b=event.values[1];
    c=event.values[2];

    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
        magnetismx.setText(Float.toString(event.values[0]));
        magnetismy.setText(Float.toString(event.values[1]));
        magnetismz.setText(Float.toString(event.values[2]));
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Recording Started" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                try {
                    writeToCsv(Float.toString(a), Float.toString(b), Float.toString(c));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use TimerContdown for every 5 sec or 10 sec. if you wan to update your UI on every 5-10 sec. either you can also use Android service and broadcast receiver .

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the code that do write the file is in the `onClick()`
this is executed only when you click the button, it's executed once.

the `onSensorChanged()` will be called, but the `onClick()` will not execute again.

you need to make a flag (boolean) that will tell when to store in the file,
this flag is changed at `onClick()`

ex,

```
boolean recording = false;

Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
        recording = true;
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Data Recording Started" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
});

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
    a= event.values[0];
    b=event.values[1];
    c=event.values[2];
    if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

        magnetismx.setText(Float.toString(event.values[0]));
        magnetismy.setText(Float.toString(event.values[1]));
        magnetismz.setText(Float.toString(event.values[2]));

        if(!recording){
            return;
        }

        try {
            writeToCsv(Float.toString(a), Float.toString(b), Float.toString(c));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***to make the button act as a switch (On, Off) change this***

```
recording = true;
```

to this

```
recording = !recording ;
```

which will reverse the current value of the boolean.
this way one click will start record, next click will stop it.

Comment: Also, i am wondering if i want to add another button to stop the record. How can i do it?

Comment: @BimalBhattarai no need for another button, check my answer, at the end i explained how to make the same button turn recording ON and OFF, if u still want another button, just add it same as first button, and onClick will have `recording=false;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `Button` out of the callback `onSensorChanged`. You don't need it there. Define the `Button` somewhere else for example in the `onCreate()` method e.g.

```
onCreate()
Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   flip = !flip;
            });
```

The boolean field `flip` is used for controlling the write behaviour of your `onSensorChanged` callback. So define a private field `flip` in your class and use it like this

```
 @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        Sensor sensor = event.sensor;
        a= event.values[0];
        b=event.values[1];
        c=event.values[2];
        if (sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {

        magnetismx.setText(Float.toString(event.values[0]));
        magnetismy.setText(Float.toString(event.values[1]));
        magnetismz.setText(Float.toString(event.values[2]));
        if(flip) writeToCsv(Float.toString(a), Float.toString(b), Float.toString(c));
    }
}
```

Comment: oh, i posted almost the same answer :)